# onDeviceReady not firing in PhoneGap hello world app

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events

I'm trying to do a simple alert('test') app, but the event isn't being fired, this is the code:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('omar');
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>AAAA</h1>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Why is this?

Comment: When does the `onLoad` function run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to make sure that document has completely loaded before adding the event listener.

Example:

HTML:

```
<body onload="onLoad">
```

JS:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
   //anything you want done after deviceready has fired
}
```

With jQuery you can use `$(document).ready()` instead of `<body onload="onLoad()">`

Example:

```
$(document).ready() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
   //anything you want done after deviceready has fired
}
```

Comment: Or Just add `();` after function definition.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather take an asynchronous approach, like so:

```
bindEvents: function () {
    var me = this;

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        me.onDeviceReady();
    }, false);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        me.onDocumentReady();
    });
},

documentReady: false,
onDocumentReady: function () {
    this.documentReady = true;
    this.checkReady();
},

deviceReady: false,
onDeviceReady: function () {
    this.deviceReady = true;
    this.checkReady();
},

checkReady: function (id) {
    if (this.documentReady && this.deviceReady) this.load();
},

load: function () {
    // do stuff
}
```

This way you don't risk attaching handlers after the event has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Cordova apps (tested on iOS and Android) and ordinary web pages. No library (jQuery) needed.

```
// Use onDeviceReady if we run in Cordova
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (window.Cordova) {
        document.addEventListener('DeviceReady', bootstrap, false);
    } else {
        bootstrap();
    }
}, false);
```

The Cordova documentation says that the [DeviceReady](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) event is made so, that it can't be missed. The handler will be called even if the device was ready before.

Answer (score -2):

Put `()` at the end of `onDeviceReady`?

```
onDeviceReady()
```

Let me know if this is right guys, it worked for me when testing on the browser

Comment: This is wrong. Adding the () will execute the function immdiately not when the event fires.