# deviceready not firing on android device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am new to phonegap and I have created the following app in node.js and I have ran the app on a samsung galaxy 1. But cant get the deviceready event to trigger. Have I missed a step?

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <!--  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" /> -->
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert("123");
    }

    </script>
</head>    


 <body>
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="addButton" value="Click To Add"/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="testButton" value="Test Data" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="deleteButton" value="Delete Data"/>
    </div>

    <div id="result">

    </div>

</body>
```

I have tried running the javascript in a separate file and using init() onload but still doesnt fire?

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you using `phonegap-1.4.1.js`. Phonegap/cordova is currently on `3.5`. You are using a very old version of phonegap. Also you need to provide the steps that you took for building the phonegap app for us to understand your problem?

Comment: just following an old tutorial I guess

Comment: what are the steps that you took to build/create the phonegap app? Please provide details ( phonegap version, platform android/IOS/blackberry version)?

Comment: I loaded node.js from command prompt, installed cordova, then cordova create hello.com.example.hello helloworld then added platform using; cordova platform add android. Built the app; cordova build and then; cordova run android to test on device

Comment: possible duplicate of [onDeviceReady not firing in PhoneGap hello world app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311805/ondeviceready-not-firing-in-phonegap-hello-world-app)

Comment: @tau can you check if there is file name called `cordova.js` in the folder `www` under `<Your Project Name>\platforms\android\assets\`.  If yes than replace that name `js/phonegap-1.4.1.js` to `"cordova.js"` in the html file.

Comment: Thanks frank that has worked.

Comment: @tau your welcome. I have add it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tau can you check if there is file name called `cordova.js` in the folder `www` under `<Your Project Name>\platforms\android\assets`.  If yes than replace that name `js/phonegap-1.4.1.js` to `"cordova.js"` in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Where is cordova.js in your project . Include cordova.js in hTML . remove this **phonegap-1.4.1.js** 
If you have cordova project