# Phonegap preferred language returns nothing

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

On a project of app with JQM and phone gap, I try to get the preferred language. I made a test on xcode emulator but nothing is returned by the method. It should work because I just made a copy-paste from the official documentation.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    });

    function onDeviceReady()
        {
        alert("before");
        navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
            function(language){$('#test18').html('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
            function(){$('#test18').html('Error getting language\n');});
        alert("after");
            };
</script>

<h3 id="test18"></h3>
```

Alert "before" is popped out but not the second one...

I even add permissions in the config.xml but it is useless as it is not needed for ios.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you waiting for `deviceready` event to fire before calling this?

Comment: I wasn't but I adapted my code in the main message. I still have the issue.

Comment: You also need to wait for the document to finish loading before setting the event listener for `deviceready`, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311805/ondeviceready-not-firing-in-phonegap-hello-world-app/13312574#13312574

Comment: I included the addEventListener into $(document).ready function but it doesn't change anything. Maybe is the document never ready but I don't know how to check it and why. It is possible it is due to a non found external file? Normally every included files (such as javascript files) are present. Chrome only returns an error for Cordova.js but this should be included in the app runned with Xcode emulator. I hope my message is clear.

Comment: There was a typo on the example. I changed again my code in the main message. I receive the first alert but not the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer :D

I thought plugins were automatically included. **I had to install the plugin Globalization** and it works.

Additional remarks: event listener deviceReady has to be created after the document is ready. Check link provided by Dawson Loudon in the comments.

Thank everybody!