# Need the document ready inside deviceready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In phonegap do I need the $(document).ready(...) inside the deviceready event function? Can I be sure that document is loaded when the deviceready event is called?

Example:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', 
   function() {
            $(document).ready(function() { // is this too much? 
                initCampusWeb(); 
            });
        }, false);
```

Comment: You have to make sure `document.ready` is called before adding the event listener for `deviceready`, it can't happen the other way

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311805/ondeviceready-not-firing-in-phonegap-hello-world-app/13312574#13312574

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that this works is `jQuery(document).ready()` fires first and then `deviceready` fires.

I generally set up my code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // do document ready stuff
}).on('deviceready', function () {
    // do deviceready stuff, put all calls to plugins in here
});
```

So the question as to where `initCampusWeb` goes depends on what you are doing inside that function. If it uses plugins, put it inside the `deviceready` handler.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't confident that deviceready would always fire after document ready, so I took the following asynchronous approach, like so:

```
bindEvents: function () {
    var me = this;

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        me.onDeviceReady();
    }, false);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        me.onDocumentReady();
    });
},

documentReady: false,
onDocumentReady: function () {
    this.documentReady = true;
    this.checkReady();
},

deviceReady: false,
onDeviceReady: function () {
    this.deviceReady = true;
    this.checkReady();
},

checkReady: function (id) {
    if (this.documentReady && this.deviceReady) this.load();
},

load: function () {
    // do stuff
}
```

This way you don't risk attaching handlers after the event has occurred. May be overkill, but gives me complete confidence and also asynchronous extensibility (in case I want load() to wait for another event to complete).

Answer (score 1):

According to the cordova documentation:

> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the
>   native code loads, a custom loading image displays. **However,
>   JavaScript only loads once the DOM loads.** This means the web app may
>   potentially call a Cordova JavaScript function before the
>   corresponding native code becomes available.
>
> **The deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. Once the
>   event fires, you can safely make calls to Cordova APIs.** Applications
>   typically attach an event listener with document.addEventListener once
>   the HTML document's DOM has loaded.
>
> The deviceready event behaves somewhat differently from others. Any
>   event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its
>   callback function called immediately.

The `$(document).on("ready")` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

you can use only `document.addEventListener('deviceready')` for that prupouse

Answer (score 1):

That is the right way:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

   // Your code here

}
```