# How to check internet network connection in Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am unable to check internet connection in phonegap.
this is what i have done so far.

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);

```
function onDeviceReady() { 

    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
           var networkState = navigator.connection.type; 
           var states = {};
           states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
           states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
           states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
           states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
           states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
           states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

           alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
       }
```

Alert dialog is not popup.

Comment: are you waiting for `document.ready` before setting the event listener? If not, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311805/ondeviceready-not-firing-in-phonegap-hello-world-app/13312574#13312574

Answer (score 0):

First need to install **[Cordova Network Information Plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.network-information)**

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
var Status = "";

function init() {  
   document.addEventListener("offline", offLine, false);
   document.addEventListener("online", onLine, false);
}

function offLine() {  
   if(Status != 'disconnected') {
      Status = 'disconnected';
     // Your code
   }
}

function onLine() { 
   if(Status != 'connected' && Status != '') {
       Status = 'connected';
       // Your code    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap to get device connection type.

1.Include the Phonegap/Cordova javascript file inside your html page.

2.Add the EventListner to load the function when device gets ready.
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", connectionType , false);

3.Create a function to get the network connection type of the device.

```
function connectionType() {
    var  networkConnectionType =  navigator.network.connection.type;
           alert('Connection Type: ' +  networkConnectionType );
}
```