# phonegap ios needs click to active event?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have add the some plugin such as device by the following:
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
Then when I try the sample code to show the device information:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Device Properties Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
    element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                        'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
}

</script>
 </head>
  <body>
<p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

but the information did not show. When I added an onClick function:

```
<script>
 function test(){
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
        'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
        'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
        'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
        'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

        </script>

        <p onclick="test();"; id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
```

The device information could be shown after I click it...

This situation only occurred in ios , my android app works well.please help~Thank you.

Comment: This answer should solve the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311805/ondeviceready-not-firing-in-phonegap-hello-world-app/13312574#13312574

Comment: Thank you Daxson Loudon~ I have try it but it still didn't work. I now remove index.js or put it in the bottom of my code, it works! But I wonder it will have any problems or not if I remove index.js or put it in the bottom of the code...Pleas help