# Cordova iOS don't respond to touchinput

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have created a Cordova app on iOS and when I try to press the button on the simulator or on a real device is is supposed to show me an alert that the button has been pressed. Unfortunately nothing happens and I'm not quite sure why. Some code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--
    Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
        https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
    Some notes:
        * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
        * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
        * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
            * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){alert('device ready');}, false);

    function showAlert(){
        alert("Button is pressed!");
    }

</script>

<h1>This is an app</h1>
<button onClick="showAlert()">Press me!</button>

</body>
```

Can someone see if I am doing an incredible stupid mistake?

Comment: Two things: 1) Use the dialogs plugin for alerts > https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs 2) You have to wait for the document to finish loading before adding the event listener for `deviceready` > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311805/ondeviceready-not-firing-in-phonegap-hello-world-app/13312574#13312574

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 5.0.0 or higher, you are required to use the `whitelist` system. It covers `CSP` (Content Security Policy), which prevents inline-javascript from working.

Your HTML element `<button onClick="showAlert()">Press me!</button>` has an *inline-javascript* element. You canNOT use that as of Cordova 5.0.0. The restriction is part of the new WebView Library (*UIWebview* and *WKWebview* for `iOS`)

To use the *inline-javascript* in your HTML you will have to write a CSP exception. NOTE: *This will make your app insecure*. You can add security by following the link just below.

Here is your code, add it to your `index.html`

 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
          content="default-src *; 
                   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">`

### NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE.

### IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.

The following link will help guide you through what you need:
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)
Best of Luck

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` actually needs to be `onclick`. That will get your your alert, but only when you lift your finger, and it will be laggy. This is because onclick is generally used for the computer. For ios with cordova you can use `ontouchstart`.