# cordova project onclick() event not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

i m new to cordova/phonegap.....just prepared a simple mobile app for my project.....works fine with mozilla firefox but the events never fire in android emulators and devices......searched a lot for soln....i've included cordova.js....seems nothing works fine...here's my javascript and html file....using jquery.mobile framework.....whats wrong with onclick() event as it works fine with mozilla browser???

```js
     function getsemester(sem)
      {
       localStorage.semester=sem;
      }
     function getbranch(br)
      {
       localStorage.branch=br;
      }
     var branches=['C.S','I.T','E.C','MECHANICAL','CIVIL'];
     
     


 
     


     function ref()
      { if(localStorage.branch==5)
       {
        if(localStorage.semester==3)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=civilsem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=civilsem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=civilsem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=civilsem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=civilsem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=civilsem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=civilsem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }
        else if(localStorage.semester==4)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=civilsem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=civilsem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=civilsem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=civilsem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=civilsem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=civilsem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=civilsem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }
       else if(localStorage.branch==2 && (localStorage.subject==12 || localStorage.subject==17))
       {
        if(localStorage.subject==12)
        {
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=itsem3[0];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=itsem3[1];
         
         
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=itsem3[2];
       

         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=itsem3[3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=itsem3[4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=itsem3[5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=itsem3[6];
        }
        else if(localStorage.subject==17)
        {
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=itsem4[0];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=itsem4[1];
         
         
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=itsem4[2];
       

         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=itsem4[3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=itsem4[4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=itsem4[5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=itsem4[6];
        }
        
       }

       else if((localStorage.branch==1 || localStorage.branch==2))
       {
        if(localStorage.semester==3)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=cssem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=cssem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         
         
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=cssem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
       

         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=cssem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=cssem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=cssem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=cssem3[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }

        else if(localStorage.semester==4)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=cssem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=cssem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         
         
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=cssem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=cssem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=cssem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=cssem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=cssem4[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }

        else if(localStorage.semester==5 && localStorage.branch==2)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=itsem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=itsem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=itsem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=itsem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=itsem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=itsem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=itsem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }

        else if(localStorage.semester==5 && localStorage.branch==1)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=cssem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=cssem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=cssem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=cssem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=cssem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=cssem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=cssem5[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }

        else if(localStorage.semester==6 && localStorage.branch==2)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=itsem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=itsem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=itsem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=itsem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=itsem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=itsem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=itsem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }

        else if(localStorage.semester==6 && localStorage.branch==1)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=cssem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=cssem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=cssem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=cssem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=cssem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=cssem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=cssem6[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }

        else if(localStorage.semester==7 && localStorage.branch==2)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=itsem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=itsem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=itsem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=itsem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=itsem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=itsem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=itsem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }
       

        else if(localStorage.semester==7 && localStorage.branch==1)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=cssem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=cssem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=cssem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=cssem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=cssem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=cssem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=cssem7[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }

        else if(localStorage.semester==8 && localStorage.branch==2)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=itsem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=itsem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=itsem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=itsem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=itsem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=itsem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=itsem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }

        else if(localStorage.semester==8 && localStorage.branch==1)
        {  
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML=cssem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))];
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML=cssem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+1];
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML=cssem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+2];
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML=cssem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+3];
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML=cssem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+4];
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML=cssem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+5];
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML=cssem8[7*(localStorage.subject-5*(localStorage.semester-1))+6];
        }
       }
        
       


         /* DEFAULT CONDITION */

       else
       {
         document.getElementById("refer1").innerHTML="nothing stored right now";
         document.getElementById("refer2").innerHTML="nothing stored right now";
         document.getElementById("refer3").innerHTML="nothing stored right now";
         document.getElementById("refer4").innerHTML="nothing stored right now";
         document.getElementById("refer5").innerHTML="nothing stored right now";
         document.getElementById("refer6").innerHTML="nothing stored right now";
         document.getElementById("refer7").innerHTML="nothing stored right now";
       
    }
   }
     function display()
      {
       document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML="Displaying subjects of "+branches[parseInt(localStorage.branch)-1]+" branch "+" Semester "+parseInt(localStorage.semester);
      }
     function display2()
      {
       document.getElementById("write").innerHTML=branches[parseInt(localStorage.branch)-1]+" branch "+" semester "+parseInt(localStorage.semester);
      }
     function abc(br)
      {
       getbranch(br);
       /*display();*/
       display2();
       sem();
      }
     function sem()
      { var i;
       i=5*(localStorage.semester-1);
       if(localStorage.branch==1)
        { document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=cssubjects[i];
         document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=cssubjects[i+1];
         document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=cssubjects[i+2];
         document.getElementById("4").innerHTML=cssubjects[i+3];
         document.getElementById("5").innerHTML=cssubjects[i+4];
     }
    else if(localStorage.branch==2)
        { document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=itsubjects[i];
         document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=itsubjects[i+1];
         document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=itsubjects[i+2];
         document.getElementById("4").innerHTML=itsubjects[i+3];
         document.getElementById("5").innerHTML=itsubjects[i+4];
     }
    else if(localStorage.branch==3)
        { document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=ecsubjects[i];
         document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=ecsubjects[i+1];
         document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=ecsubjects[i+2];
         document.getElementById("4").innerHTML=ecsubjects[i+3];
         document.getElementById("5").innerHTML=ecsubjects[i+4];
     }
    else if(localStorage.branch==4)
        { document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=mesubjects[i];
         document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=mesubjects[i+1];
         document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=mesubjects[i+2];
         document.getElementById("4").innerHTML=mesubjects[i+3];
         document.getElementById("5").innerHTML=mesubjects[i+4];
     }
    else if(localStorage.branch==5)
        { document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=civilsubjects[i];
         document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=civilsubjects[i+1];
         document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=civilsubjects[i+2];
         document.getElementById("4").innerHTML=civilsubjects[i+3];
         document.getElementById("5").innerHTML=civilsubjects[i+4];
     }


   }


  function getsubject(sub)
   { // add if statements
    localStorage.subject=sub;
    diskitaab();
    ref();
   }
  function diskitaab(br)
   {   if(localStorage.branch==1)
    { document.getElementById("kitaab").innerHTML="You chose "+branches[localStorage.branch-1]+" branch "+" semester "+localStorage.semester+" subject "+cssubjects[localStorage.subject];
     document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML=cssubjects[localStorage.subject];
    }
    else if(localStorage.branch==2)
    { document.getElementById("kitaab").innerHTML="You chose "+branches[localStorage.branch-1]+" branch "+" semester "+localStorage.semester+" subject "+itsubjects[localStorage.subject];
     document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML=itsubjects[localStorage.subject];
    }
    else if(localStorage.branch==3)
    { document.getElementById("kitaab").innerHTML="You chose "+branches[localStorage.branch-1]+" branch "+" semester "+localStorage.semester+" subject "+ecsubjects[localStorage.subject];
     document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML=ecsubjects[localStorage.subject];
    }
    else if(localStorage.branch==4)
    { document.getElementById("kitaab").innerHTML="You chose "+branches[localStorage.branch-1]+" branch "+" semester "+localStorage.semester+" subject "+mesubjects[localStorage.subject];
     document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML=mesubjects[localStorage.subject];
    }
    else if(localStorage.branch==5)
    { document.getElementById("kitaab").innerHTML="You chose "+branches[localStorage.branch-1]+" branch "+" semester "+localStorage.semester+" subject "+civilsubjects[localStorage.subject];
     document.getElementById("sub").innerHTML=civilsubjects[localStorage.subject];
    }
   }
```

```css
downloaded flat_ui css and included it in html file
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/classic-theme.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/overwrite.css">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/overwrit.js"></script>
        


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.flatui.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>




        <title>My app</title>
   

    </head>
   

    <body>

    
     <div id="year" data-role="page" data-title="year" data-theme="a">

      <div data-role="header" data-id="head" data-position="fixed"> 
       
       <h3>Select year</h3>
       
      </div><!-- header -->

      <div data-role="content">
       <div data-role="controlgroup">
        <div data-role="collapsibleset">
         <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
          <h3>I year</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" class="pd">
           <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="getsemester(1)" data-icon="carat-r">I SEM</a></li>
           <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="getsemester(2)" data-icon="carat-r">II SEM</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div><!-- collapsible -->
         <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
          <h3>II year</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" class="pd">
           <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="getsemester(3)" data-icon="carat-r">III SEM</a></li>
           <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="getsemester(4)" data-icon="carat-r">IV SEM</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div><!-- collapsible -->
         <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
          <h3>III year</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" class="pd">
           <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="getsemester(5)" data-icon="carat-r">V SEM</a></li>
           <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="getsemester(6)" data-icon="carat-r">VI SEM</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div><!-- collapsible -->
         <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
          <h3>IV year</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" class="pd">
           <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="getsemester(7)" data-icon="carat-r">VII SEM</a></li>
           <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" onclick="getsemester(8)" data-icon="carat-r">VIII SEM</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div><!-- collapsible -->
              </div>
             </div><!-- controlgroup -->
      </div><!-- content -->

      <div data-role="footer" data-id="foot" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="#settings" data-icon="gear" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#course" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="flip"></a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div><!-- footer -->
    
     </div><!-- year -->




     <div id="branch" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

      <div data-role="header" data-id="head" data-position="fixed"> 
       <h3>Select Branch</h3>
      </div><!-- header -->

      <div data-role="content">
       <div data-role="controlgroup">
        <ul data-role="listview">
         <li><a href="#subject" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-icon="carat-r" onclick="abc(1)">C.S</a></li>
         <li><a href="#subject" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-icon="carat-r" onclick="abc(2)">I.T</a></li>
      <li><a href="#subject" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-icon="carat-r" onclick="abc(3)">E.C</a></li>
         <li><a href="#subject" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-icon="carat-r" onclick="abc(4)">Mechanical</a></li>
         <li><a href="#subject" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" data-icon="carat-r" onclick="abc(5)">Civil</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div><!-- controlgroup -->
      </div><!-- content -->

      <div data-role="footer" data-id="foot" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="#settings" data-icon="gear" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#year" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="flip"></a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div><!-- footer -->
     </div><!-- branch -->




     <div id="subject" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

      <div data-role="header" data-id="head" data-position="fixed"> 
       <h3>Select Subject</h3>
      </div><!-- header -->



      <div data-role="content">
      
         <h6>Displaying subjects of</h6>
          <h5 id="write"></h5>
       
          <a href="#books" data-transition="fade" data-role="button" id="1" onclick="getsubject(5*(localStorage.semester-1))"></a>
       <a href="#books" data-transition="fade" data-role="button" id="2" onclick="getsubject(5*(localStorage.semester-1)+1)"></a>
       <a href="#books" data-transition="fade" data-role="button" id="3" onclick="getsubject(5*(localStorage.semester-1)+2)"></a>
       <a href="#books" data-transition="fade" data-role="button" id="4" onclick="getsubject(5*(localStorage.semester-1)+3)"></a>
       <a href="#books" data-transition="fade" data-role="button" id="5" onclick="getsubject(5*(localStorage.semester-1)+4)"></a>
      
        </div><!-- content -->



      <div data-role="footer" data-id="foot" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#settings" data-icon="gear" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#branch" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="flip"></a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div><!-- footer -->
     </div><!-- subject -->

     

          <!-- ****Books Here***** -->



     <div id="books" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

      <div data-role="header" data-id="head" data-position="fixed"> 
       <h3>Reference Books</h3>
          <a href="#info" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog"></a>
      </div><!-- header -->

      <div data-role="content">
       <div id="kitaab"></div>
       <center><h3 id="sub"></h3></center>
       References:
       <ul>
         <li id="refer1"></li>
         <li id="refer2"></li>
         <li id="refer3"></li>
         <li id="refer4"></li>
         <li id="refer5"></li>
         <li id="refer6"></li>
         <li id="refer7"></li>
       </ul>

      </div><!-- content -->

      <div data-role="footer" data-id="foot" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
              <li><a href="#settings" data-icon="gear" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
         <li><a href="#subject" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="flip"></a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div><!-- footer -->
     
     </div><!-- books -->

    <div data-role="page" id="info" data-theme="a">
      
      <div data-role="header" data-id="head" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>:D</h3>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
        <center><h3>KEEP CALM</h3>
        <h5>and refer</h5>
        <h2>SHIVANI</h2></center>
      </div>
     
     </div><!-- dialog -->

     <div id="settings" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

      <div data-role="header" data-id="head" data-position="fixed"> 
        <h3>Settings</h3>
      </div><!-- header -->

      <div data-role="content">
         <a href="index.theme1.html" data-role="button">Change Theme</a>
      </div>

      <div data-role="footer" data-id="foot" data-position="fixed">
       <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home" iconpos="notext"></a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div><!-- footer -->
     </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you load jQuery from an external source? First it will slow down your app and second the user needs to be online, that means it costs some traffic/money.

Comment: SEE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828827/cordova-ios-dont-respond-to-touchinput/33840906#33840906

Comment: but I've not used CDN.....I've downloaded jQuery.min.js from its official site and included it within www folder and referred to it from index.html.....app is completely offline.....I've done the same for jQuery.mobile.min.CSS as well as jQuery.mobile.min.js.......but keeping that aside.....why onclick () doesn't work???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova/Phonegap requires the Content-Security-Policy tag (*[Info Here](http://www.content-security-policy.com)*) which is present in cordova projects by default.

This tag is basically prevents/allows certain security-related content policies.

Your tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

To use inline javascript on your page you should add `'unsafe-inline'` right after (with a space) the `https://ssl.gstatic.com` to all content-security-policy tags of the pages on which you want to use inline js.

For more info on how to use content-security-policy tag see the link at the top of this answer.