# Phonegap not play mp3 file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I try to implement an audio file to my phonegap app, inside my config.xml file i have this :

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"/>
```

and in my index.html file :

```
<button onclick="playAudio('recit.mp3')">Play Some Audio</button>

function playAudio(src) {

        if (device && device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
        }
        var media = new Media(src, success, error_error);
        media.play();
    }
```

when i run app on browser i got this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined
```

I noticed also than in my project directory i have not the : /android_asset/www/ directories, but in /platforms/android/ i have them

Do i have to create those directories ? why i have "device is not defined" error?

Thansk for your help guys.

Comment: for the file path try `file:///android_asset/www/` instead of `/android_asset/www/` also device will not be available until cordova finishes loading, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311805/ondeviceready-not-firing-in-phonegap-hello-world-app/13312574#13312574 as you cannot call anything cordova related until the `deviceready` event has fired. Also, in browser, device does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

"device" var is set by an other plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

So, you have to add:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm"/>
```

on your config

In your test you should also write:

```
if (window.device && window.device.platform == 'Android')
```